# How to replace text in a text file?

Tags: java, logic, concept

I have a file `String.xml`, as shown:

```xml
<resources>
<string name="app_name">SoundAndBackground</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

I am trying to develop a Java program which can store the words coming after:

```xml
 ">
```

Such as:

```
SoundAndBackup
Settings
Hello world
```

And store these words in array, so that I can replace these with other words.

How to make this type of Java program?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ Read the tutorial, its quite easy

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the JDOM and DOM libraries which are great for parsing in data for XML files.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/) is a quick JDOM tutorial and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) is a DOM tutorial. If you are undecided as to which one you should use [here is a thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/128860/XML/JDOM-DOM) discussing the merits of both.

**EDIT** (in response to comment):

If you want to develop an application with the general logic that can apply to text files then using regex in conjunction with String objects would be your port of call. If you are unfamiliar with regex there are tonnes of resources on the web. You can find a simple tutorial [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, I am not specific with only xml files. I am trying to develop a logic which can also applicable to txt files

Comment: I do _not_ recommend using the same approach for XML files and simpler text files.  For a simple text file, you can probably use regular expressions (see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)).  But XML files are structured and have a syntax, and attempting to use regular expressions to parse those is generally a bad idea and could bring on the apocal&^#$&*@&&7&#^@ --um, never mind.